# spoofer.js: An unexpected error has occurred, should I be concerned?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, spoofing

I am usinng Firefox version 105.0.2 (64 bit), and noticed that for every single page I visit, in the Dev Console there is an error:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred 
spoofer.js:1:38935
```

Link to the full code:
https://pastebin.com/GhiEvqfg

The specified line:

```
e.runtime.lastError ? e.runtime.lastError.message === t ? n() : r(e.runtime.lastError) : o && o.__mozWebExtensionPolyfillReject__ ? r(new Error(o.message)) : n(o)
```

I do not know what this file or this line does, but should this be something that should be of a concern?

Comment: did you fix it , i even dont know how i got this problem too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, was a extension named "Simulateur Mobile" (https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/simulateur-mobile).
After disabling that extension, the error is gone.